# Need help understanding differentiation. Question and Answer provided

Tags: calculus

[image]

Could someone walk me through this derivative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you linked corresponds to a simple case of [Leibniz's Rule for Differentiating Integrals](http://www.cis.udel.edu/~breech/physics/physics-notes/node10.html).

Note, however, that there is an obvious typo in that solution: there should be $ - \frac{1}{k}Qf(\frac{Q}{k})$ instead of $ - \frac{1}{k}Q (\frac{Q}{k})$.

EDIT: While the solution you linked is instructive, it is by far not the simplest one. In particular, note that
$$
\frac{d}{{dQ}}\int_{Q/k}^\infty  {Qf(x)dx}  = \frac{d}{{dQ}}\bigg[Q\int_{Q/k}^\infty  {f(x)dx} \bigg] = \bigg[1 - F\bigg(\frac{Q}{k}\bigg)\bigg] + Q\frac{d}{{dQ}}\bigg[1 - F\bigg(\frac{Q}{k}\bigg)\bigg].
$$